How can I set the application file description in C# (.NET 8)?
I'm building an application in .NET 8 and I can't find the option to set the exe file description, the one displayed in Task Manager as the application name. I was able to do it in .NET Framework, but now it just displays the exe file name (assembly name).
I can't even find the option in the .csproj file.


In the csproj you can create an element inside a property group called Description which should do it.

@RyanThomas I've already tried it, but it doesn't work on .NET 8. Task Manager and the taskbar still show the assembly name.

You need to set the AssemblyTitle.
<PropertyGroup>
   <AssemblyTitle>A Custom File Description</AssemblyTitle>
</PropertyGroup>


